Understanding an approximate method for quantum mechanics
My teacher gave us a pdf with the theory but I can't understand 2 things from it. The pdf is the book Quantum Mechanics by Cohen-Tannoudji et al, page 1305, which you can read on the Internet Archive here.
Refer to the XIII's chapter, it talks about methods to approximate the energies of problems dependent of t, context may be necessary so that's why I added the pdf.
In any case, this is the page that concerns me, I'll write it in code:

For the approximate solution of the Schrödinger equation, we can have $\{|\phi_n\rangle\}$ for the eigenstates of $H_0$ such that $H=H_0+\lambda*\hat{W}$. Let $c_n$ be the components of the ket $|\psi(t)\rangle$ in the $\{|\phi_n\rangle\}$ basis: $$|\psi(t)\rangle=\sum_n c_n(t)|\phi_n\rangle$$ with $c_n=\langle\phi_n|\psi(t)\rangle$, while $\hat{W_{nk}}(t)=\langle\phi_n| \hat{W}(t)|\phi_k\rangle$ and as $H_0$ is a diagonal matrix we have $\langle\phi_n|H_0|\phi_k\rangle=E_n \delta_{nk}$. If we finally project both sides of the Schrödinger equation onto $|\phi_n\rangle$ we get the equation B-6:
$$i\hbar \frac{d}{dt} c_n(t)=E_n c_n(t)+\sum_k \lambda \hat{W_{nk}} c_k (t)$$ When $\lambda$ is zero and the solution is very simple. But if $\lambda$ isn't zero but much smaller than $H_0$ we can parametrise and get B-8: $$c_n(t)=b_n(t) e^{-iE_n t/\hbar}$$.
If we combine B-6 and B-8 and simplify we get B-11: $$i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}b_n(t)=\lambda \sum_k e^{i\omega_{nk}t} \hat{W_{nk}}(t) b_k(t)$$ with $\omega_{nk}=\frac{E_n-E_k}{\hbar}$ after multiplying by $e^{+i E_n t/\hbar}$ on both sides. To find the solution for small $\lambda$ we can form the solution in the power series expansion: $$b_n(t)=b_n^{(0)}(t)+\lambda b_n^{(1)}(t)+\dots$$. If we substitute this expansion into B-11 we get for the order $r=0$ to get B-13 after equation the powers of $\lambda^r$: $$\mathbf{i\hbar \frac{d}{dt} b_n^{(0)}(t)=0}$$ and for $r\neq 0$ we get B-14: $$\mathbf{i\hbar \frac{d}{dt} b_n^{(r)}(t)=\sum_k e^{i\omega_{nk}t} \hat{W_{nk}}(t) b_k^{(r-1)}(t)}$$

I don't understand how they got the equations B-13 and B-14.
For B-13. I was trying to understand how the terms of $\lambda^0=1$ on the right hand side could be zero but I don't understand how, the sum isn't necessarily zero nor the $\hat{W}_{nk}(t)$ is. Though I do understand the left hand side.
For B-14. I don't understand only where the $r-1$ comes from on the order of $b_k$ on the right, I get it that it's trying to get a recursive formula but why is it $r-1$ instead of $r$ and the solution for $r=0$ is $0$ and for $r\geq 1$ is that expression shown? Instead of the $r-1$ which I don't understand

For B-13, there are no terms of order $\lambda^0$ on the righthand side. The $\lambda$ before the sum in B-11 ensures that. As for B-14, the $\lambda$ in B-11 bumps the $b^{(0)}_k(t)$ term up to order $\lambda^1$, the $b^{(1)}_k(t)$ term up to order $\lambda^2$, and so on. That's why it's $r-1$.

Okay I understood the B-13 but still don't understad B-14, can you expand it a little bit more?

Here's a very, very simplified version. Suppose we start with $b = \lambda b$ (Eq. 1), and expand $b$ as $b = b^{(0)} + b^{(1)}\lambda + b^{(2)} \lambda^2 + ...$. Plugging the expansion of $b$ into Eq. 1, we have $b^{(0)} + b^{(1)}\lambda+... = \lambda\left(b^{(0)} + b^{(1)}\lambda + ...\right) = b^{(0)} \lambda + b^{(1)} \lambda^2 + ...$. Equating the coefficients of like powers of $\lambda$ on both sides, we get the sequence of equations $b^{(0)} = 0$, $b^{(1)} = b^{(0)}$, $b^{(2)} = b^{(1)}$, and in general $b^{(r)} = b^{(r-1)}$.
